# Adicionar elementos em um array através de um foreach

Tags: php, mysql

Não consigo adicionar elementos em um array através de um foreach

Meu array $agendas:

```
array(7) { [0]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["cliente_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["usuario_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["unidade_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["antecedencia_abertura"]=> string(2) "30" ["dt_registro"]=> NULL ["dt_atualizacao"]=> NULL } [1]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["cliente_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["usuario_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["unidade_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["antecedencia_abertura"]=> NULL ["dt_registro"]=> string(19) "2019-08-01 11:27:07" ["dt_atualizacao"]=> NULL } [2]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["cliente_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["usuario_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["unidade_id"]=> string(2) "19" ["antecedencia_abertura"]=> NULL ["dt_registro"]=> string(19) "2019-08-01 11:27:28" ["dt_atualizacao"]=> NULL } [3]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "8" ["cliente_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["usuario_id"]=> string(2) "29" ["unidade_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["antecedencia_abertura"]=> NULL ["dt_registro"]=> string(19) "2019-08-09 21:08:34" ["dt_atualizacao"]=> NULL } [4]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "9" ["cliente_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["usuario_id"]=> string(2) "29" ["unidade_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["antecedencia_abertura"]=> NULL ["dt_registro"]=> string(19) "2019-08-09 21:08:36" ["dt_atualizacao"]=> NULL } [5]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(2) "11" ["cliente_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["usuario_id"]=> string(2) "28" ["unidade_id"]=> string(2) "19" ["antecedencia_abertura"]=> NULL ["dt_registro"]=> string(19) "2019-08-27 01:43:29" ["dt_atualizacao"]=> NULL } [6]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(2) "12" ["cliente_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["usuario_id"]=> string(2) "28" ["unidade_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["antecedencia_abertura"]=> NULL ["dt_registro"]=> string(19) "2019-08-27 01:43:30" ["dt_atualizacao"]=> NULL } }
```

É percorrido por esse Foreach:

```
$paginationBloqueios = [];
    foreach ($agendas as $agenda) {
        array_push($paginationBloqueios, $agendaBloqueio->getPageBloqueios($agenda['id'], $pageBloqueios));
    }
```

Que é enviado para minha view:

```
'bloqueios'             => $paginationBloqueios['data'],
```

Meu mysql:

```
public static function getPageBloqueios($agenda_id, $page = 1, $itemsPerPage = 10)
{

    $start = ($page - 1) * $itemsPerPage;

    $sql = new Sql();

    $results = $sql->select("
                                    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
                                      tb_usuario.apelido,
                                      tb_agenda_bloqueio.id,
                                      tb_agenda_bloqueio.dt_inicio_bloqueio,
                                      tb_agenda_bloqueio.dt_fim_bloqueio
                                    FROM  
                                      tb_agenda_bloqueio
                                    INNER JOIN tb_agenda
                                      ON tb_agenda.id = tb_agenda_bloqueio.agenda_id
                                    LEFT JOIN tb_usuario
                                      ON tb_usuario.id = tb_agenda.usuario_id
                                    WHERE 
                                      tb_agenda_bloqueio.agenda_id = :agenda_id
                                    LIMIT $start, $itemsPerPage;
                                    ", array(
                                        ":agenda_id" => $agenda_id
                                    ));

    $resultTotal = $sql->select("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS nrtotal;");

    return [
        'data'  => $results,
        'totalBloqueios' => (int)$resultTotal[0]["nrtotal"],
        'pagesBloqueios' => ceil($resultTotal[0]["nrtotal"] / $itemsPerPage)
    ];

}
```

Estou recebendo os erros:

Notice: Undefined index: pagesBloqueios in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\app\Controller\Sistema\BloqueioController.php on line 138

Notice: Undefined index: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\app\Controller\Sistema\BloqueioController.php on line 154

Comment: Parece que esses erros acontecem em outra parte do código. De qualquer maneira, pelo que você mostra não existe `$paginationBloqueios['data']`, e sim `$paginationBloqueios[0]['data']`, `$paginationBloqueios[1]['data'] `, etc.

Comment: O erro acontece nessa linha 'bloqueios' => $paginationBloqueios['data'] e em outra linha que está usando o retorno da Query getPageBloqueios.